# Can I send sound to a speaker?

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

Can I send the sound (byte array) to the speaker? I know about DirectShow, but it doesn't work in UWP. I don't want to use the `Media Foundation`, because I can't add a new audio frames to `AudioGraph` if they're not in the format `(32 bit; Stereo; 48 kHz; IEEE Float)`. If I try to add an `AudioFrame` from another `AudioGraph`, it works.

Edit:
Or should I use WASAPI? Can I only use the c ++?

Comment: [WASAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371455.aspx) exposes its services as COM interfaces. As such, they are immediately consumable from any managed programming language using COM interop.

Comment: I can recommend search sample code - [Windows-universal-samples-master](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). It includes sample - WindowsAudioSession. I think it includes all your need code. WindowsAudioSession is written on c++.

Comment: Thank you all. It's a good sample. 

I downloaded this sample from this page: [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Audio-Session-22dcab6b), but your sample is better, @Evgeny Pereguda.